# Computing the difference of min/max of two columns, per group, using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given the following dataset:

| group_id | from_date | to_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 |
| 0 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-01 |
| 0 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-01 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-01 |

I'm trying to compute, *for each group*, `max(to_date) - min(from_date)`, such as the result looks like (+- some days depending on months duration):

| group_id | duration_days |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 90 |
| 1 | 60 |

Using the following correctly computes the duration, but returns an ungrouped dataframe of 5 rows:

```
groupby(["group_id"])
  .apply(lambda x: x.assign(duration_days=(np.max(x["to_date"])-np.min(x["from_date"])).days))`
```

I've tried using `aggregate` but I haven't managed to make it work with a function using two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach was almost correct, just aggregate as Series and take care of renaming afterwards:

```
# ensure datetime
df['from_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from_date'])
df['to_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['to_date'])

(df.groupby('group_id')
   .apply(lambda g: g['to_date'].max()-g['from_date'].min())
   .reset_index(name='duration_days')
)
```

output:

```
   group_id duration_days
0         0       91 days
1         1       60 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us not do with apply lambda. `melt` + `np.ptp`

```
out = df.melt('group_id').groupby('group_id')['value'].agg(np.ptp).reset_index(name = 'duration_days')
Out[16]: 
   group_id duration_days
0         0       91 days
1         1       60 days
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't really compute the `max(to_date) - min(from_date)` but a global max-min (which shouldn't matter if the dataset is logical)

Comment: Thank you. It does matter in this case unfortunately, since each group has its own set of consecutive time periods, with overlaps… Thanks for the note, @mozway

Answer (score 1):

Compute the maximum and minimum per group (I am making sure they are datetime objects, they probably are already):

```
maxi = df.groupby('group_id').to_date.max()
mini = df.groupby('group_id').from_date.min()
```

Then subtract them from each other:

```
(maxi - mini).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   group_id  to_date
0          0 91 days
1          1 60 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
# previous conversion to datetime
cols = ['from_date', 'to_date']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)

(df.pivot_table(values=cols, index='group_id', aggfunc={
               cols[0]: 'min', cols[1]: 'max'})
 .assign(duration = lambda x: x.pop('to_date').sub(x.pop('from_date')))
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   group_id duration
0         0  91 days
1         1  60 days
```